# How can I get html onchange function to work when page loads

Tags: html, onchange

I have an onChange function that works on the booking form that I have created but when the update form I have created loads I cant find a way of filtering as if it has been selected, below is a snippet of the code used which repeats for each element that is filtered;

```
<input name="CQty" id="CQty" value="<?php echo $noc; ?>" onChange="if (this.value=='1'){this.form['C1N'].style.visibility='visible'}"
```

Here is where I am at with the jquery attempt so far (although it is shortened compared to the length of the final requirement);

```
document.onload = function clientQty() {
var Qty = document.update.CQty;
  if (['#CQty'].value=='1'){
      $['#C1N'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Al'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Gen'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1DOB'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Age'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Rel'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1IDNo'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Photo'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1PoC'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1PKB'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Res'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C2N'].style.visibility='hidden'
      $['#C2Al'].style.visibility='hidden'
      $['#C2Gen'].style.visibility='hidden'
      $['#C2DOB'].style.visibility='hidden'
      $['#C2Age'].style.visibility='hidden'
      $['#C2Rel'].style.visibility='hidden'
   }
else if (['#CQty'].value=='10'){
      $['#C1N'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Al'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Gen'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1DOB'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Age'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Rel'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1IDNo'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Photo'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1PoC'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1PKB'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C1Res'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C2N'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C2Al'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C2Gen'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C2DOB'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C2Age'].style.visibility='visible'
      $['#C2Rel'].style.visibility='visible'
}
};
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated as it is the only thing that I am stuck on now.

Comment: try `document.onload`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you provide that `document.onload` code

Comment: Are you basically trying to hide different parts of the form based on which value is selected in that input? Also what type of input is it? What is the value when it loads?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (document.getElementById("number").value=='1'){
      this.form['C1N'].style.visibility='visible'
   }
};
```

give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your PHP scripts, so to test this, I changed your HTML so the input value defaults to `1` like so:

```
<input name="CQty" id="CQty" value="1" onChange="if (this.value=='1'){this.form['C1N'].style.visibility='visible'}">
```

And your JavaScript to this:

```
window.onload = clientQty;

function clientQty() {
  console.log($('#CQty').attr('value')) //1
  //OR
  console.log(document.getElementById('CQty').value) //1
  //change all of these selectors so they work like the ones in the console.log statement
};
```

Your selectors aren't working properly. If you are using jQuery selectors (ie `$`), you can't reference those elements the way you would reference regular DOM elements in JavaScript as you do when you write `.style.visibility = 'visible'`-- you have to use jQuery functions like I did in `$('#CQty').attr('value')` above. The reverse is also true -- you can't use JavaScript DOM elements in jQuery without turning them into jQuery objects.

To try this, I would recommend viewing the console (Google how to do it in your browser of choice) and making sure that you have a value for those `console.log` statements when the page loads. If the value is undefined, your `if` statement will never be true, because `undefined` is not equal to `1`.

One last note -- look into the meaning of `this` in JavaScript. In the line `onChange="if (this.value=='1'){this.form['C1N'].style.visibility='visible'}"` you say `this.form`, but `this` in that context is the input, and my guess is it doesn't have a form property.

Comment: Thank you, all that info was a big help, I will give the edits that you have suggested a go tomorrow.